# Reuse everything from a React component except its render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, one which I'd like to inherit all class functions and state from the other, but update the render method. Is there a way to do this cleanly in React?

```
class A extends Component {
  state = {
    ...
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      ...
    });
  }
  changeText = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  changeType = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      type: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  ...
}
```

```
class B extends Component {
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What you have shown should work, just remember NOT to call `super.render()`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) is what you are looking for.

HOCs are a technique in React for reusing component logic, so you can write everything you want to share in a HOC and wrap each component in need with it

Answer (score 1):

What you have provided should already work although you have to extend Component B from A. Like this:

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: "Hello"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({text: "Hello World"});
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>I am A.</h1>
  }
}

class B extends A {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.state.text + " in B."}</h1>
  }
}
```